# Faulting application <app_name>, version <version number>,faulting module kernel32.dll

Tags: c#, .net, windows, kernel32

I have one windows application built using C# and .net framework 2.0 and its  installed on Windows Server 2003.

I have tested application on my machine and it works perfectly on my machine. Only difference between two machines is that, my machine has Windows Vista OS and machine on which error occured has Windows Server 2003 OS.

When I start application, it works correctly for some time but then gives one error as

> Faulting application ,
>   version ,faulting
>   module kernel32.dll,version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp , debug? 0. fault address 0x000bef7.

Source : .NET Runtime 2.0 Error
Category : None
Event ID : 1000

Does anyone knows why this error is coming? I googled for this error but most of the solutions were for either explorer.exe or internet explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use windbg or adplus to attach to the process and get the process crash dump. This would help you to identify the offending part of the code with symbols loaded. In most cases, it shows the last exception and hence gives a very good view of what could have gone wrong.

Comment: @Sarvanan, Thanks for guidance. I will try to get the process crash dump.